# How to pass RawQuery from AppSync to Lambda?

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server, aws-appsync

I'm using AppSync a GraphQL API for my Lambda function which is basically is NestJS Apollo Server.
When I try this query

```
query defaultSearch($accountId: String!) {
  defaultSearch(accountId: $accountId) {
    maxPrice
  }
}
```

What I see in the event sent from AppSync to my Lambda is

```
{
    "request": {
        "arguments": {
            "accountId": "SOMESTRING"
        },
   "info": {
            "fieldName": "defaultSearch",
            "parentTypeName": "Query",
            "variables": {
                "accountId": "SOMESTRING"
            }
        },
}
```

And this doesn't allow me to pass the query correctly to my Apollo Server. is there a way to get the rawQuery? like

```
"query {\n  defaultSearch(accountId: \"SOMESTRING\") {\n    maxPrice\n  }\n}"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up writing my own handler function to parse the AppSync event as the following.

Giving that i'm receiving this from AppSync Event

```
"info": {
        "selectionSetList": [],
        "selectionSetGraphQL": "",
        "fieldName": "getLocations",
        "parentTypeName": "Query",
        "variables": {
            "region": "BERLIN"
        }
    },
```

for the following Query

```
query getLocations($region: SupportedRegions!) {
getLocations(region: $region)
}
```

I get the Schema that was defined for my Apollo Server

```
const { schema } = app.get(GraphQLSchemaHost);
```

The helper function is like this

```
function generateGraphQLQuery(eventInfo, operationSchema) {
    const { fieldName, parentTypeName, variables, selectionSetGraphQL } = eventInfo;
    const queryArgs = operationSchema.args
        .map(arg => {
            if (variables[arg.name]) return `$${arg.name}: ${arg.type}`;
        })
        .filter(Boolean)
        .join(', ');
    const queryPlaceholders = Object.keys(variables)
        .map(variable => `${variable}: $${variable}`)
        .join(', ');

    return {
        query: `${parentTypeName.toLowerCase()} ${fieldName} (${queryArgs}) {
            ${fieldName}(${queryPlaceholders})
            ${selectionSetGraphQL}
        }`,
        variables,
    };
}
```

`operationSchema` is just the definition that I got from my registered Schema for that operation. Hope that it is helpful :)